# MySQL join 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, join, solution

I have a database with users. Now I'm trying to create a wall (Facebook like).
I've added a table in my db called status_update and added a row username(user who posted the status). Then I created a query to search for statuses from the user on whose profile page you're on (select from status where `username=$_GET['profile']`).

I'm wondering how smart this is? Is there a way to use `JOIN` or something? Now this was the only logic solution that came to my mind and I know how to make it.

Also this is fine for this page but when I'll create a feed page for those who are "Friends or Followers" that's gonna be a bit tricky.

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can join two tables by there index or any value, just do it like this

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table.field=table.field
```

it depends what join you want, inner join if data present on both table other wise left if data may or may not present

Comment: So if I do it like select * from status inner join user on status.username=user.username?

Will I get information from table status where usernames are the same?

Sorry would test it but not home ATM.